# Vector space clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm asked to decide if the following are vector spaces.

A=$\{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}:\int_0^1|f(x)|dx=0$ $\}$

B= $\{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}:f'(x)+4f(x)=0$ and  $f(0)=1 $}

C=$\{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}: \int_0^1 f(x)dx=1\}$

D=$\{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}: f'(x)+4f(x)=0 \}$

My apprach: B and C fail closure under addition. A and D is a vector space.

Part A I'm not very sure about though because of the absolute value. Can I get confirmation that Part A *does* satisfy closure under addition? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f_1,f_2\in A$ so that $\int_0^1 |f_i(x)|\,dx=0$ for $i=1,2$. Then 
\begin{align*}
0
&\leq \int_0^1|f_1(x)+f_2(x)|\,dx \\
&\leq\int_0^1\big(|f_1(x)|+|f_2(x)|\big)\,dx \\
&=\int_0^1|f_1(x)|\,dx+\int_0^1|f_2(x)|\,dx \\
&=0+0 \\
&=0
\end{align*}
Hence $f_1+f_2\in A$.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Do you also agree with B and C in that they are not vector spaces?

Comment: @User69127 Yes I agree with your reasoning.